# Preventing back and forward buttons from reloading the page in a single page app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a single page app in which the page is never unloaded. I am using the # in the url and using javascript to detect the hashchange and then updating the UI using JS and AJAX... and I **do not** want the forward and back buttons to make an extra request to the server.

Currently, the first time the user initially comes to the site, a server request is made (which is OK)

```
Processing by MyController#index as HTML
```

My goal is for this server request to only happen once during the users time at the site...every time they click on any other link, I just use the "#" in the url to prevent a new server request... so all my "a" tags look like something like this

`<a href="#page1/`

The issue I am having is that clicking the back and forward button triggers my JS hashchange listener (which is what I want)... but it also calls

```
Processing by MyController#index as HTML //I DO NOT WANT THIS TO HAPPEN
```

Here is the functionality I am currently getting

1.) user navigates to mydomain.com

2.) "Processing by MyController#index as HTML" is launched and a server request is made (THIS IS OK)

3.) User clicks a link and now the url reads mydomain.com/#page1 and I update the view with JS (THIS IS OK)

4.) User clicks a link and now the url reads mydomain.com/#page2 and I update the view with JS (THIS IS OK)

5.) User clicks BACK and now the url reads mydomain.com/#page1 and I update the view with JS (THIS IS OK)

6.) a server request is AUTOMATICALLY made to reload the page ("Processing by MyController#index as HTML" is called again) (THIS IS **NOT** OK)

**How do I prevent step 6 from occuring when the user clicks the back button??... I just want the url to change and for me to update my UI via JS and no server request**

Also, I am using ruby on rails if this helps at all.

Comment: Not sure this is possible. Upvoted.

Comment: You can try to use HTML5 History API http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/history.html

Comment: You did not say explicitly how you arrive to step 6. Are you saying that once on step 5, your page automatically jumps to step 6?

Comment: @ghybs YES. This is exactly what happens

Comment: Strange, there should normally be no network transaction when the back / forward buttons trigger only a fragment (hash) change

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is impossible.  You can't override the default behavior of browser buttons like back/forward/stop/refresh, etc.

What you could do is create your own Back and Forward buttons (and place them on the actual page, itself) - and code their event handlers accordingly to make your AJAX calls.

Comment: all I am trying to do is prevent step 6 from occurring automatically... Is this really not possible?

Comment: @YaseenAniss to the best of my knowledge, yes.  I will check back on this thread, though, in case I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This work fine for me
[jQuery hashchange event](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it figured it out. For some reason, Turbolinks was causing it to reload the page whenever the back or forward button were clicked. I removed the Turbolinks gem from the app and now its all working perfect.